# How to use RNS domains with non-fungible token standards? (such as ERC721)

Tags: dns, subdomain, solidity, smartcontracts, rsk

I have registered a `.rsk` domain using [RNS](https://developers.rsk.co/rif/rns/),
and am wondering if I can transfer ownership of it to other accounts,
like an NFT.

Is this possible with domains and subdomains? If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the domains that are created with the new
[FIFS Registrar](https://developers.rsk.co/rif/rns/architecture/rsk-registrar/registrars/fifs/),
or migrated using
[migrate from auction](https://developers.rsk.co/rif/rns/operations/migrate-from-auction/)
are ERC721 compatible.

(Note that the above **only** applies to domains;
**subdomains** are not tokenised,
and not ERC721 compatible.)

The following are the relevant lines of code within the RNS smart contracts:

`FIFSRegistrar` -->
[(inherit) `FIFSRegistrarBase`](https://github.com/rnsdomains/rns-rskregistrar/blob/94b7226c29a2c76cb5f234c86a1a0fc8ff600aba/contracts/FIFSRegistrar.sol#L9) -->
[(property) `NodeOwner`](https://github.com/rnsdomains/rns-rskregistrar/blob/94b7226c29a2c76cb5f234c86a1a0fc8ff600aba/contracts/FIFSRegistrarBase.sol#L27) -->
[(inherit) `ERC721`](https://github.com/rnsdomains/rns-rskregistrar/blob/94b7226c29a2c76cb5f234c86a1a0fc8ff600aba/contracts/NodeOwner.sol#L9) -->
[(property) `tokenId`](https://github.com/rnsdomains/rns-rskregistrar/blob/94b7226c29a2c76cb5f234c86a1a0fc8ff600aba/contracts/NodeOwner.sol#L113)

---

Details

(inherit) `FIFSRegistrarBase` in `FIFSRegistrar.sol#L9`

```
contract FIFSRegistrar is FIFSRegistrarBase, PricedContract {
```

(property) `NodeOwner` in `FIFSRegistrarBase.sol#L27`

```
    NodeOwner nodeOwner;
```

(inherit) `ERC721` in `NodeOwner.sol#L9`

```
contract NodeOwner is ERC721, Ownable, AbstractNodeOwner {
```

(property) `tokenId` in `NodeOwner.sol#L113`

```
        uint256 tokenId = uint256(label);
```